# How to control regions of an image in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm learning android,so   I'm trying to develop a board game, wherein the user moves a coin to a particular position on the game board. How to animate/ the moving of the coin to that particular region. I have an image of the board,and image of the coin. However, I'm not sure how to move the image to a particular position on the board and make the same code work for several screen configurations. I know to move an image we can use property Animation. However, I'm not sure how to move to a particular exact location on the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little broad, you might want to start your task by looking for a [Drag and Drop](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) Tutorial.

[This Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html) is probably one of the best structured ones, but there's lots of them, just Google 'android drag and drop example' .

Comment: This is what I'm exactly looking for!